# Segment a list into unequal sublists based on sublist index

Tags: r

x is the list and y are the cutting points of the series of list, I have tried with cut and split (using factor and as below), however does not work.

```
x <- list (c( 1,2,3 ), c(2,3,4) , c(5,6,7) , c(3,2,1) , c(5,4,2) , c(3,2,5))
y <- c(2, 3, 4)
```

Desired output

```
[[1]]
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3
[[2]]
[1] 2 3 4

[[2]]
[[1]]
[1] 5 6 7

[[3]]
[[1]]
[1] 3 2 1
[[2]]
[1] 5 4 2
[[3]]
[1] 3 2 5
```

Comment: You need to find a way to convert your "y" to something that looks like this: `c(1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try with `Map`

```
Map(function(i, j) x[i:j], c(1, y[-1]), c(y[-length(y)], length(x)))
#[[1]]
#[[1]][[1]]
#[1] 1 2 3

#[[1]][[2]]
#[1] 2 3 4


#[[2]]
#[[2]][[1]]
#[1] 5 6 7


#[[3]]
#[[3]][[1]]
#[1] 3 2 1

#[[3]][[2]]
#[1] 5 4 2

#[[3]][[3]]
#[1] 3 2 5
```